# Lógica de uma tabela de Likes

Tags: php, mysql, lógica

Em uma aplicação PHP + MySQL na qual preciso armazenar quantos likes + id's de quem deu like em uma publicação, me veio uma dúvida para com a lógica.

Supondo que 2 usuários dão like na mesma postagem ao mesmo tempo, e ambos executam:

```
UPDATE te_anuncios
SET curtidasTotal = curtidasTotal + 1,
    curtidasIds   = curtidasIds + idNovo; //iria geral algo como '23, 31, 43, 44, 32...'
```

Preciso tratar esse update no PHP, para adicionar o ID do novo curtidor, certo?

```
<?php
  $idsAtuais .= ", {$_SESSION['userId']}";
```

Meu receio é de que, enquanto o PHP trata os IDs atuais para concatenar na string do banco de dados, outra pessoa dê um like e capture os valores do banco sem o ID que está sendo tratado e sobreponha ele quando completar.

Haveria uma forma mais inteligente que pudesse inibir esse problema? Talvez rodar algo diretamente no MySQL.

Comment: Sua preocupação é coerente, pois é nítida a concorrência neste caso. No entanto, a estrutura da sua tabela, que não me parece a ideal, é a que propicia tal situação. Pesquise sobre relacionamentos entre tabelas e veja como implementar a estrutura da relação "muitos para muitos" (no inglês, *many-to-many*).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso é questão de normalização do seu banco de dados, sempre que você tem a relação de `N:N` é necessário criar uma tabela auxiliar.

Crie um tabela que contenha o `id` da postagem e o `id` do usuário:

Quando algum usuário curtir uma postagem, você faz o `insert`, quando ele descurtir você faz um `delete`.